# Implicitely converting one templated class into another

Tags: c++

I have a `Vector` class and a `Span` class (a bit like the std ones), and I want the Vector to be convertible to a Span. That mostly works, but I have still one issue when calling template functions where the template argument deduction fails, and I can't figure out why.

Here's a minimal example (and [compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/TMbdrrGrW)):

```cpp
template <class T>
struct Span {};

template <class T>
struct Vector
{
    operator Span<T>() { return {}; }
};


void print_span_int(Span<int>);

template <class T>
void print_span(Span<T>);


void test()
{
    Vector<int> vec;

    print_span_int(vec);        // ok
    print_span(vec);            // error
}
```

I tried adding a deduction guide, but that doesn't help:

```cpp
template <class T>
Span(Vector<T>&) -> Span<T>;

print_span(Span(vec));      // now I can do that though :|
```

Is it possible to make `print_span(vec);` compile without having `Vector` inherit `Span`?

Comment: you cannot have implicit conversion and deduction at the same time. There is potentially an infinite number of ways to instantiate the function template and find a matching conversion

Comment: i would include the error message in the quesiton rather than only in the external link (but thats not about focus)

Comment: The error message is different for each compiler but it's along the line of "cannot deduce argument type" without a clear explanation. It's one click away on the compiler explorer link.

Comment: this has nothing to do with template class, template deduction doesn't consider conversion.

Comment: Can't have an implicit conversion and a deduction at the same time? That sounds very sad :( Is there a work around for a case like that?

Comment: Consider researching `concepts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have implicit conversion to a deduced type, or rather: deduction deos not take implicit conversions into account. You expect `Vector<int>` to convert to `Span<int>`, but in principle there is an infinite number of potential candidates. There could be a `Span<foo>` specialization that can be constructed from a `Vector<int>`. There could be a different `Span<bar>` specialization that can be constructed from a `Vector<int>` too. In general checking all possible combinations is not possible, and would lead to ambiguity often. None of this is the case in your example, though rather than even attempting to go this route, implicit conversions are not taken into account for deduction. The way out is to not rely on implcicit conversions.

The basic idea is to make `print_span` accept all types `T` but then restrict it to only those that can be converted to a `Span<T::value_type>`. I am not fluent with concepts, so I will show you the somewhat hacky sfinae way, though modernizing it should be straight forward if you are familiar with concepts.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <class T> struct Vector;

template <class T>
struct Span {
    using value_type = T;  
};

template <class T>
struct Vector {
    using value_type = T;
    operator Span<T>() { return {}; }
};

template <class T>
Span(Vector<T>&) -> Span<T>;

template <class T>
void print_span(Span<T>) { std::cout << "span<T>\n";}

template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v< T,Span< typename T::value_type>>,void>
 print_span(const T& t){ std::cout << "T\n"; }

int main() {
    Vector<int> vec;
    print_span(Span(vec));      
    print_span(vec);   
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bjn6rdMz5)

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations! Honestly that's going to make me reconsider making Vector inherit Span I think haha. I've got a ton of existing functions like print_span and making a second version for things convertible to Span is not super enticing.

Comment: @Jerem Nooooo. Inheritance is not the right solution here. Inheritance is extremely overrated. Some pretend it would be the solution to everything, but it is not.

Comment: @Jerem don't miss that my answer is mainly about the principle. With concepts the principle will be the same: You accept all types, but only those that can be converted to the one you want. But with concepts its more easier to express. Sfinae is a hack, while concepts are designed for just such stuff. It wont be much more complicated or clunky than your original code. Unfortunately I don't know eough about concpets to write an answer. Maybe with some trial and error I could get some code to compile, but thats not enough to write an answer

Comment: Thanks, it's fine, I don't have access to concepts yet anyway. I will think about solutions to make that work without inheritance.

Comment: @Jerem the thing is that inheritance comes with a whole bag of other things. Implicit conversions are often a pain in the xxx rather than something desriable. I understand that and why you want implcicit converions here, but using inheritance for only that reason isn't sound imho

Comment: I agree, I agree. Inheritance is definitely not a good solution in this example. One issue is that Span and Vector constness are very incompatible (const Vector implies the content is const, which is not the case for Span).